# How to sequence a query in F#?

Tags: casting, f#, sequence

So I have a [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) like this one

```
let query = 
    query {
        for person in people do
        select person
    }
```

And I'd like to have it [sequenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences).

```
let sequence : seq<Person> = query
```

But I can't find any information on how to do it, maybe I've become bad at using search engines.

I'm getting unexpected type compiling expections using things like `|> seq.ofList` and `ToList()`.

> The expression was expected to have the type `seq<Person>` but here has the type `Generic.List<Person>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of a `query` expression has type `IQueryable<_>`, which is a subtype of `IEnumerable<_>` (for which `seq<_>` is a synonym), so you can simply change the type:

```
let mySeq : seq<_> = myQuery
```

Or, if you want to avoid a type annotation, use the built-in [`seq` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.seq%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), which does the same thing:

```
let mySeq = seq myQuery
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is it equivalent to `ToList`/`ToArray` in C#/VB.NET?

Comment: No, that would be calling ``mySeq |> Seq.toList`` or ``mySeq |> Seq.toArray``.

Comment: @dumetrulo, so to have the query executed, `Seq.toList` or `Seq.toArray` have to be called first?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "executed".

Comment: Is a new sequence created, separate of the query (result stored in an array), or is the query evaluated everytime the sequence it iterated?

Comment: The latter option. Casting `query` to a supertype (which is [what the `seq` function does](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/63db27cc32d78c1e774f7e3100a0933d0474509a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3303)) doesn't do anything with its value. It's still a query, it's still going to be executed when you enumerate.